# TeamCity - Web Deploy with MSBuild and the file system

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I just want to build the source and copy it to another folder but I have something wrong or I'm not getting it or both:

```
/p:Configuration=Release 
/p:OutputPath=bin 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://{server}:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:username=**** 
/p:password=**** 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=test.livesite.com 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

What I really want is to just have it build and on success copy to: D:\f1\f2\website. How do I do this?

I made some changes and now here's where I'm at:

```
Build 
MSBuild 
src\ZooKeeper.Web\ZooKeeper.Web.csproj 
MSDeployPublish 
VSMSDeploy 
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4377, 5): error 
ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC: Web deployment task failed. 
(Could not connect to the remote computer ("ZooKeeper") 
using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not 
respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote
computer.  Learn more at:     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.) 
Project src\ZooKeeper.Web\ZooKeeper.Web.csproj failed. 
src\ZooKeeper.Web.Tests\ZooKeeper.Web.Tests.csproj 
Project src\ZooKeeper.Web.Tests\ZooKeeper.Web.Tests.csproj failed. 
    Project src\ZooKeeper.Web.sln failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web deploy requires lots of stuffs to install, perhaps you have omitted something ?

Follow this great tutorial : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx (it worked perfectly for me)

Comment: I actually have 3 build steps. One does the build, one runs the test and the 3rd is the deployment step. It's giving me an error: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Comment: It would have been great to specify this in your original post, can you add it ? I will modify my answer in consequence.

Comment: You were right. I thought I had that installed but all I had done was update the web platform installer. I did that and it went great.