# Provide credentials to MSBuild publish step that uses FileSystem deployment in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I work in a dev environment where the computers aren't part of a domain. I'm trying to set up TeamCity 8.05 on one of the computers to publish check-ins to a test server for our QA team. I've got it working the way I want when I deploy to local directories on the TeamCity server, but when I try to publish to the QA server I run in to permissions problem. I have a share on the QA server with a local user who I want to authenticate with when doing my publish. Is this possible with MSBuild?

Command line switches to my MSBuild runner in TeamCity look like this:

```
/p:PublishProfile=./Alpha.publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:Configuration=Alpha /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 
/p:UserName=QAServer\BuildUser /p:Password=somepass
```

The Alpha.publish file looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Alpha</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\QAServer\Alpha</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I get an 'Access to the path \\QAServer\Alpha is denied' message when this step runs. I assume this is because the build agent runs as a system account which can't access the QAServer.

I'm trying to avoid the overhead of using Web Deploy, but [it looks like that would work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989691/teamcity-web-deploy-with-msbuild-and-the-file-system) if this isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Sayed I. Hashimi ‏on twitter:

> FileSystem relies on windows auth. Passing in password is ignored.
>   Your build user will need write access

That's what I thought. My solution is to publish to local staging directory first, then use the [SMB Deployer from the TeamCity Deployer plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) to move the files across the network. The plugin allows you to specify credentials.